# mod_rewrite and dynamic pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried following a tutorial on the internet about mod_rewrite but it wasn't really for me. I created a .htaccess file that has the following code for now:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options +Indexes  
RewriteEngine On
```

From what I understand this is the basic setup of .htaccess to rewrite urls, followed by the instructions... what and how to change. I tried different exampled but it didn't worked for me. I have a dynamic page with the url `localhost/alpha/oferta.php?id=52042156c65d4`, where id="..." is the unique id of that offer. I want to change it to localhost/alpha/oferta/id=".."
Can you please show me an example of how can I achieve that? Also if you know any helpful tutorials let me know. Let me know before downrating so I can edit my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want this kind or URL : `localhost/alpha/oferta/id=123abc` to be redirected to `localhost/alpha/oferta.php?id=123abc`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options +Indexes  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^alpha/oferta/id=([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ alpha/oferta.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Remember a few things :

- this **won't** magically change "old" URLs into "new" ones. You must use rewritten ("new") URLs everywhere. Then your htaccess will change this readable URL into a technical one, which can be used by your code.
- this redirection is transparent. If you want the URL to change into the browser bar, use `[L,R=301]` instead of `[L]`.
- this will only accept letters (case insensitive) and numbers for your `id`.
- you can find a good cheat sheet about `mod_rewrite` [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as).